# Navigation Through Component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I can navigate perfectly through View using [routerLink]. When I am trying to navigate through Component using **this.router.navigate(['/Todos'])** or **this.router.navigateByUrl('/todos')**, initially the router is changing correctly to **index.html#/todos** and then the router is automatically changing to **index.html?#/login**. I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**app.component.js**

```
(function (app) {

app.AppComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
            directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
            viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: [ng.router.Router, ng.http.Http, function (router, http) {

            }],
        });

ng.router
        .RouteConfig([
          { path: '/login', component: app.LoginComponent, name: 'Login', useAsDefault: true },
          { path: '/todos', component: app.TodosComponent, name: 'Todos' },
        ])(app.AppComponent);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**boot.js**

```
(function (app) {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ng.core.provide(ng.router.LocationStrategy, { useClass: ng.router.HashLocationStrategy })]);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**login.js**

```
(function (app) {

    app.LoginComponent = ng.core
            .Component({
                selector: 'login',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: [ng.router.Router, function (router) {
                    this.router = router;
                }],
                onSubmit: function (form, user) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/Todos']);
                    //this.router.navigateByUrl('/todos');
                },
            });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.router.navigate(['Todos'])` without `/`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. That too also produces the same problem.

Comment: Also, I have tried with this.location.go('/todos') by injecting ng.router.Location. In this, the URL is changed correctly, but the component is not loaded. Still I remain in the login page.

Comment: `this.router.parent.navigate(['Todos'])` might be another option. I don't know about routing myself yet :-/

Comment: What happens if you delete/comment `/login` route?

Comment: `this.router.parent.navigate(['Todos'])` also gives the same problem.

Comment: Why I need to delete/comment `/login` route? If I delete/comment, how can I try navigate from a page to todos page?

Comment: I created a plunkr to try to reproduce your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/w61Ecbmuj7EfDnsYEHOS?p=preview. When you say "the router is automatically changing to index.html?#/login", you mean automatically? Could you have a look at my plunkr and tell if you can reproduce your problem? Thanks!

Comment: @AbrahamA I didn't mean permanently delete (: Just for debugging... does it give you any errors? Does it still try to navigate to `/login`?

Comment: Thierry: Thanks for the Plunker. Plunker is working 100% fine. But still I am not able to solve my problem. Is this problem existing that I am running in visual studio localhost?

Comment: @Thierry Could you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: @AbrahamA Could you add the content of the `login.html` file? Your JavaScript seems correct to me...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: I tried by referring your plunker and found the issue which is there in my html form. If I remove the angular form, it is working perfectly. The following is my template for your reference `<form #simpleForm="ngForm" novalidate>

    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(simpleForm, user)">Login</button>

</form>`. Can you tell me why the angular form is producing navigation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your latest comment, I think that you're problem is linked to the way you submitted your form:

```
<form #simpleForm="ngForm" novalidate>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
           [(ngModel)]="user.name" ngControl="name"
           #name="ngForm" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(simpleForm, user)">Login</button>
</form>
```

You should leverage the `submit` event on the form directly, as described below:

```
<form #simpleForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(simpleForm, user)">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
           [(ngModel)]="user.name" ngControl="name"
           #name="ngForm" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/w61Ecbmuj7EfDnsYEHOS?p=preview.

Comment: Can you see this [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76HM1TSxBQIWXRYZklmN3JBYmc/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76HM1TSxBQIWXRYZklmN3JBYmc/view?usp=sharing) and tell me why the error is coming when I submiited the form and navigatted to next page.